# Error LNK2028 when calling exported C function from C++ wrapper

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, dllexport

I have C project from which I export function `f()` and call it from other C++ project and it works fine. However, when I call some other function `g()` inside `f` I get LNK2028 error.

The minimal example of `C`project looks like:

Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include "myfunc.h"
#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT void f()
{
    g();    // this will provide LNK2028 if f() is called from other project
}

#endif
```

myfunc.h

```
void g();
```

myfunc.c

```
#include "myfunc.h"
void g(){}
```

The project itself is being built. However, when I call this function from other `C++/CLI`project

```
#include "Test.h"
public ref class CppWrapper
{
 public:
    CppWrapper(){ f(); }   // call external function        
};
```

I get error:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00007C) "void __cdecl g(void)" (?g@@$$FYAXXZ) referenced in function "extern "C" void __cdecl f(void)" (?f@@$$J0YAXXZ)   main.obj    CppWrapper
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl g(void)" (?g@@$$FYAXXZ) referenced in function "extern "C" void __cdecl f(void)" (?f@@$$J0YAXXZ)    main.obj    CppWrapper
```

Additional details:

1. I set x64 platform for whole solution
2. In CppWrapper I include `.lib` file from C project

Comment: Try declaring the body of `f` in another source file instead of the header. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: @MaxTruxa No, when in `Test.c` include `Test.h` I get compile error for C2059 for  `EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT` before `void f()`.

Comment: Remove the `EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT` from your source file. You only need to include this in the header file.

Comment: @MaxTruxa I didn't include it in source file. In `Test.h` I left `EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT void f();`. In `Test.c` I write `#include "Test.h"` and `void f(){}`; It is not compiling (C2059).

Comment: You have to `__declspec(dllimport)` your function from your CLR project. I will build you a solution when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#ifdef BUILDING_MY_DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL_EXPORT void f();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**Test.c**

```
#include "Test.h"
#include "myfunc.h"

void f()
{
    g();
}
```

In your C project you have to add `BUILDING_MY_DLL` to

```
Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions
```

The only real change is that I added the toggle between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)`. Changes required:

- Moved `f`'s body to `Test.c` because functions imported with `__declspec(dllimport)` cannot have a definition already.

Other changes:

- Do never write `extern "C"` without an `#ifdef __cplusplus` guard, or many C compilers will not compile your code.

Comment: It works perfect! I lost last 8 hours trying to make this work. Many tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 2 days fighting this exact same problem.  Thank you for the solution.  I'd like to extend it.

In my case, I am calling a c function from an exported c++ dll function and I was getting the same error.  I was able to fix it so (using your example)

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#ifdef BUILDING_MY_DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "myfunc.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```